# python - requests.get() returns: 400

Tags: python, python-requests

```
>>>user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36'    
>>>url = 'http://xueqiu.com/stock/quote.json?code='    
>>>results = requests.get(url,params={'q': 'SZ000858'}, headers={'User-Agent': user_agent})    
>>>print results
<Response [400]>
```

Above are the codes which I want to get data from the url, while the results shows that "reponse [400]".It looks like a bad request.  I can't figure out what's wrong with it and ask for the solution.   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code and I get `api_invalid_access_token` which implies you need an API token to be able to use it.

You might want to look into the documentation for the API you're using before you use it. You most likely need to register with the provider first.

Comment: >>> r = requests.get('http://xueqiu.com/stock/quote.json?code=SZ000858')
>>> r.status_code
400
>>> r.text
u'{"error_description":"api_invalid_access_token","error_uri":"/stock/quote.json","error_code":"400016"}'              yep,  just as the codes show,   this is the problem I faced, how to solve it?

Comment: @schloss I don't know anything about the API or even how to find its documentation. I really can't help you with this little information.